# My jquery hide and show() don't work on canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

So, I'm trying to get into jquery. I have a script and I;m trying to apply jquery functions to a canvas. It won't happen though.

```js
$(document.ready)(function(){
  $("#example").hide(300).show(500);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="example" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"><canvas/>
<div/>
```

Maybe i cannot apply jquery to canvases.

Comment: What behavior do you expect from this?

Comment: $(document).ready not $(document.ready). This is a simple typographical error, and so I have flagged it as such.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will compile. You missed the parenthesis around $(document)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example").hide(300).show(500);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <canvas id="example" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"><canvas/>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo Error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").hide(300).show(500);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/bokce2p5/3/

Answer (score 0):

In your code the ready function is wrong.
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });

use the following code. It's work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#example").hide(300).show(500);

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure jQuery is linked to your html by placing your script tag with link in the head.

Then use defer, like this:

```
<script defer src="filelocation"></script>
```

Also, make sure the jQuery script is placed above your local file, as JavaScript is read from top to bottom.

And I noticed your closing tag for script is misspelled.

And your closing tags should look like `</div>` and not `<div/>`.

Comment: Well, I didn't expect so much response. Thank you guys for the help, you cannot imagine how much I need it.

Comment: @markolosole if any of the answers helped you solve your issue, remember to accept it as an answer to the question.